# raspberry pi iptables forward DNS requests over VPN

Tags: vpn, dns, iptables, raspberry-pi, wireless-access-point

I have used and slightly modified the [rpi-wifi script](https://github.com/lukicdarkoo/rpi-wifi) to set up a WiFi access point while using the standard WiFi connections. All is good.

I want to setup ExpressVPN and have all traffic go through it. This also works briefly, and it starts to fail because the DNS lookups fail.

I'm not sure what info you will need so I'll outline what I've setup.

- I have `wlan0` set up as a standard wireless interface (192.168.1.0/24).
- Using the `rpi-wifi` script above, I've created an Access Point interface `ap0` (10.10.1.1/24)
- When I connect ExpressVPN, it creates a tunnel interface `tun0`
- `dnsmasq`, `hostapd` and `dhcpcd` are used in the harming of the above

The only deviation from the iptables script was just to do the following:

```
#sudo iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o wlan0 -j MASQUERADE # Allows data over non-VPN connection
sudo iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o tun0 -j MASQUERADE
```

When the Pi boots (The VPN is not connected and with the top iptables line uncommented) everything works perfectly. Devices can connect via the `ap0` interface, browse and do all the things you'd expect.

When I connect to the VPN, this continues briefly (until the DNS needs re-querying). If I try connecting to a service via IP address, it all works fine which means the connectivity is fine it's the DNS lookups that are not.

Looking at `/etc/resolv.conf` at each stage, everything looks good. When the VPN is disconnected the nameserver is my broadband router. When ExpressVPN is connected it sets up its own nameserver, but accessing the Pi via the `wlan0` over SSH, and everything works as expected on the commandline. All traffic (including DNS) originating on the Pi goes over the VPN.

When a device connects to the `ap0` interface, it is told the nameserver is 10.10.1.1 (the `ap0` address and default gateway). This seems ok because if I'm quick, the DNS cache remembers IP addresses for a while after the VPN connection.

For the record, I know **VERY** little about iptables and all that malarky.

So, what did I try, well, lots of stuff. The only thing that currently makes any sense (bearing in mind my previous comment) and given that I can see my broadband router from the PI at all times, was to do something a bit NAT like for anything coming off the `ap0` interface for DNS port things. I think that's this:

```
sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i ap0 -p tcp --dport 53 -j DNAT --to 192.168.1.254:53
sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i ap0 -p udp --dport 53 -j DNAT --to 192.168.1.254:53
```

That didn't work, so I tried the VPN nameservers since all the other traffic goes down there...

```
sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i ap0 -p tcp --dport 53 -j DNAT --to 10.27.0.1:53
sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i ap0 -p udp --dport 53 -j DNAT --to 10.27.0.1:53
```

Some scripts on the net seemed to want to setup connections going the other way or having some `ACCEPT` commands on the go. I tried dozens of examples around this kind of stuff:

```
sudo iptables -A FORWARD -i tun0 -o ap0 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -A FORWARD -i ap0 -o tun0 -j ACCEPT
```

But all a big nope. I also tried a couple of `-j MASQUERADE` things, some `-j REDIRECT` things, and found that the `-o` flag doesn't work on `PREROUTING`

Here is the output from `iptables -S` and the contents of my `resolv.conf` when everything but DNS is working as it should (I did note that there was a UDP connection for port 53 traffic, but no TCP one, adding the TCP entry did nothing.

```
pi@trmnr:~ $ sudo iptables -S
-P INPUT ACCEPT
-P FORWARD ACCEPT
-P OUTPUT ACCEPT
-N xvpn
-N xvpn_dns
-N xvpn_dns_iface_exceptions
-N xvpn_dns_ip_exceptions
-N xvpn_ks
-N xvpn_ks_iface_exceptions
-N xvpn_ks_ip_exceptions
-A OUTPUT -j xvpn
-A xvpn -j xvpn_dns
-A xvpn -j xvpn_ks
-A xvpn_dns -j xvpn_dns_iface_exceptions
-A xvpn_dns -j xvpn_dns_ip_exceptions
-A xvpn_dns ! -o lo -p udp -m udp --dport 53 -j DROP
-A xvpn_dns_ip_exceptions -d 10.44.0.1/32 -p udp -m udp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
-A xvpn_ks -j xvpn_ks_iface_exceptions
-A xvpn_ks -j xvpn_ks_ip_exceptions
-A xvpn_ks -p udp -m udp --dport 67:68 -j ACCEPT
-A xvpn_ks ! -o lo -j DROP
-A xvpn_ks_iface_exceptions -o tun0 -j ACCEPT
-A xvpn_ks_ip_exceptions -d 10.0.0.0/8 -j ACCEPT
-A xvpn_ks_ip_exceptions -d 172.16.0.0/12 -j ACCEPT
-A xvpn_ks_ip_exceptions -d 192.168.0.0/16 -j ACCEPT
-A xvpn_ks_ip_exceptions -d 169.254.0.0/16 -j ACCEPT
-A xvpn_ks_ip_exceptions -d 224.0.0.0/24 -j ACCEPT
-A xvpn_ks_ip_exceptions -d 78.157.221.58/32 -j ACCEPT

pi@trmnr:~ $ cat /etc/resolv.conf
# Generated by expressvpn
search expressvpn
nameserver 10.44.0.1

pi@trmnr:~ $ sudo iptables -S -t nat
-P PREROUTING ACCEPT
-P INPUT ACCEPT
-P POSTROUTING ACCEPT
-P OUTPUT ACCEPT
-A POSTROUTING -o tun0 -j MASQUERADE

pi@trmnr:~ $ sudo iptables -S -t mangle
-P PREROUTING ACCEPT
-P INPUT ACCEPT
-P FORWARD ACCEPT
-P OUTPUT ACCEPT
-P POSTROUTING ACCEPT
pi@trmnr:~ $
```

Here is my `/etc/dnsmasq.conf` file.

```
interface=lo,ap0
no-dhcp-interface=lo,wlan0
bind-interfaces
server=8.8.8.8
domain-needed
bogus-priv
dhcp-range=10.10.1.50,10.10.1.150,12h
```

For the `server` bit, I thought that ExpressVPN might be filtering out google name servers for DNS leak issues, so I changed this to my broadband router (192.168.1.254) which is visible on the box (if you're ssh'd in) but this still did not work. One thought I had was setting PiHole up, and then routing all traffic through that, but if I could do that, I would be able to realistically redirect traffic to my Broadband router anyway.

Also on the hitlist was setting a route so that the google DNS went over the `wlan0`. But that did not resolve the issue.

```
pi@trmnr:/tmp $ sudo route add -host 8.8.8.8 gw 192.168.1.254
pi@trmnr:/tmp $ route
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         10.128.0.5      128.0.0.0       UG    0      0        0 tun0
default         192.168.1.254   0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 wlan0
dns.google      192.168.1.254   255.255.255.255 UGH   0      0        0 wlan0
10.0.0.0        192.168.1.254   255.0.0.0       UG    0      0        0 wlan0
10.10.1.0       0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 ap0
10.128.0.1      10.128.0.5      255.255.255.255 UGH   0      0        0 tun0
10.128.0.5      0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 tun0
46.244.28.176   192.168.1.254   255.255.255.255 UGH   0      0        0 wlan0
128.0.0.0       10.128.0.5      128.0.0.0       UG    0      0        0 tun0
172.16.0.0      192.168.1.254   255.240.0.0     UG    0      0        0 wlan0
192.168.0.0     192.168.1.254   255.255.0.0     UG    0      0        0 wlan0
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 wlan0
```

So can anyone please help me getting DNS lookups working from a client with the VPN connection? feel free to ask for more information so I can look to diagnose what's going on.

Thanks.

Comment: If your clients are talking to dnsmasq for their DNS queries, where is dnsmasq forwarding them to? (Which server, over which interface, from what source address?) What rules are in the other iptables tables (-t nat, -t mangle)?

Comment: Added dnsmasq.conf and explained a bit about the name servers being google, and my broadband router with no success. Also added a bit on route management to try and force the google name server requests over `wlan0` connection. Also added outputs from requested tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the reason why it didn't work: The `dnsmasq` has been setup to forward DNS queries to google's DNS, a route had been added to route to this host always directly, but:

```
-A OUTPUT -j xvpn
-A xvpn -j xvpn_dns
-A xvpn_dns -j xvpn_dns_iface_exceptions
-A xvpn_dns_ip_exceptions -d 10.44.0.1/32 -p udp -m udp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
-A xvpn_dns ! -o lo -p udp -m udp --dport 53 -j DROP
```

This chain of iptables rules (obviously added by ExpressVPN) drops all DNS traffic to a non-localhost interface, for which there hasn't been an exception inside the `xvpn_dns_iface_exceptions` chain.

So the solution is either to configure ExpressVPN not to drop any non-VPN DNS traffic, or "quick and dirty" to add an exception inside iptables (note the insert command instead of append to be sure to be in front of the `-A xvpn` rule):

```
iptables -I OUTPUT 1 -p udp --dport 53 -d 8.8.8.8 -j ACCEPT
```

Comment: Perfect, thanks Martin :)